# Cakephp: cascading select boxes in a view

Tags: cakephp, cascadingdropdown

I need a form with cascading select boxes where the option selected in one affects the options contained in the other. Does anoyone have a sample code that implements this? Is it just a matter of building ajax code into the .ctp file to repopulate the 2nd select control?

BTW, I'm using cake 1.3.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to implement a special action for the second select box in your `controller`, that is called via ajax and just gets the data depending on the input

```
function get_second_sb_data($in) { .. }
```

and [return a json object](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1291/Request-Handling), to populate the other SB